# Is there a Clojure equivalent of Ruby's #tap method

Tags: ruby, clojure

Ruby provides the `#tap` method, which allows you to take in a variable and run code on it, but then return the original variable rather than the result of your expression, ie:

```
def number
  5.tap { |x| print x }   # Prints 5, and returns 5
end
```

Is there any function built into Clojure that can provide this functionality?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're looking for [doto](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doto). Here's your example, rewritten using it:

```
(doto 5
  println)
```

It works similarly to the [->](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E) macro in that it passes the value through a series of functions. A key difference is that it returns the initial value you passed in, rather than what is returned by the final function.